# The type 'Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to c# and I just started learning GUI, but this gives out an error and I don't know why (I've added a reference to System.Windows.Forms)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Project2
{
    class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Form mf = new Form();
            mf.Text = "Title";
            mf.Height = 200;
            mf.Width = 300;
            Application.Run(mf);

        }
    }
}
```

The line causing the error (The type 'Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced) is: `Application.Run(mf);`

Comment: You've added a `using` statement for System.Windows.Forms. Have you also added the actual reference under References in Solution Explorer? In any case you need both more references and more code to get a basic Forms application working. Why not use the IDE wizard to create a new Forms project for you? (File | New Project | Windows Forms App).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yeah I've added the reference using Solution Explorer. Also, could you explain why this isn't enough for a simple Forms application? I'm following a C# book where the same code is used and it all works, I know I could use a Forms project, but this way is a bit simpler for me to understand and also as i said I'm following a book.